# Jpa repository return just one row when using findAll for entities with many-to-many relation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, many-to-many, jparepository

I have 2 Entities with many-to-many relation (Customer, has a list of coupons he purchased). When i'm trying to find all relations between them, I get only one row.

This is the method i'm using in the repository(CouponRepository - JpaRepository<Coupon, Integer>) :
List findAllByCustomersId(int customersId)

Those are my Entities:

```
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "customers_vs_coupons", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "coupon_id"))
    private List<Coupon> coupons;
}
public class Coupon {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private double price;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "customers_vs_coupons", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "coupon_id"))
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Customer> customers;
}
```

Comment: your ManyToMany configuration is wrong check this tutorial: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/
offtopic: id should be type Long

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mapped them correctly so try to implement this way.

Coupon.java.

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "coupon", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "customers_vs_coupons", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "coupon_id"))
    private List<Customer> customer;
```

Customer.java.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(name = "customers_vs_coupons", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "coupon_id"))
    private List<Coupon> coupon;
```

After this try to use your findAllByCustomersId